# Suggestions for timer in golang

Tags: go, timer

I am trying to make a simple 4 lane obstacle course game in golang and I want some help in the process regarding the use of time function and the speedup process.

```
d_time := delay_time
s_time := time.Now()  //time at start of program
while 1 {
    s :=random(0:3)  //total no of obstacles
    for j:= 1; j<=s; j++{
      random(1:4)   //the lane to put the obstacles
    }
    c_time := time.Since(start)
    if s_time - c_time >= 100 && d_time >= 100{
      s_time = c_time
      d_time = d_time - 50
      delay(d_time)
    }else{
      delay(d_time)
    }
}
```

Hey guys, this is basic pseudocode to speed up the game after some time and I wanted to ask if this code will be better or to directly speed up after a certain obstacle is passed.
like after 10 obstacles or so.

```
while 1 {
  for i := 0; i <= 10; i++{
    code
  }
  d_time = d_time - 50
  delay(d_time)
}
```

It would be much appreciated if you could tell me how I can show the timer while making it faster according to the speed of the game.

Comment: Seems strange to change the speed of a timer.  Most folks are familiar with the length of a second.  Instead of speeding up your clock; make your map move faster and leave the timer the same

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the built-in time function is tied to the OS. This is for example the reason why we cannot time travel while testing(cron tasks for example). And there is no plan nor will to change that. So you will have to write your own ticker and use it instead of the built-in time.